Apache Cordova: sync data/settings between devices
For an Apache Cordova app that has user preferences/data stored locally, how can I add the ability for users to sync / pull the preferences/settings to other devices? (e.g., user is upgrading their device, and wants their settings/notes pulled in). Appears the app automatically transfers from one phone to another, but the local data stays on current device only.
The app is currently available on both Android/iOS.
Thanks.
